# Asterisk AMD detection issues with WombatDialer

Tags: asterisk

we have been having issues with AMD detection when running outbound campaigns on Asterisk that seem to be load-related, but I'm not really sure.

What we do is to send outbound IVRs that are basically targeted at debt collection. We use WombatDialer as the dialing engine (so we get recalls and clustering for free, and still can program Asterisk directly) and routinely include app_AMD for machine detection. We run Asterisk 1.8.10, installed from source.

What we notice is that when we have more than 50-60 calls on one  server, we get a lot of false positives - that is an abnormal rate or AMD recalls. We were able to instrument the dialplan and see that the issue seems to be with the AMD application. Servers are pretty much idle at 50-60 calls, so it does not seem to be a problem with CPU load.

Anybody has an idea where to go from here? or how to tune AMD / get debug info out? we could easily fan out to more servers, but.... does not seem like a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Most likly at 60 calls your provider start say something like "all lines are busy now".